# Venting a hot garage, how much cooler can it get with an exhaust fan?

Tags: garage, exhaust-fan, cooling, venting

I life in Miami and the garage gets very hot in the summer and I am trying to cool it down so I can workout in it. The basics are: I'm looking at this product: iLiving - 10" Wall Mounted Exhaust Fan - Vent Fan For Garage Ventilation, 600 CFM, 900 SQF Coverage Area. Installing it as high as I can and as far from the garage door as I can. The garage door has a screened row at the bottom for airflow intake. So the airflow will help even thou the temperatures may still be in the mid 80s. Thanks, Todd

Comment: What are the dimensions of your garage? The best you can hope for is the outside temperature.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the screened row at the bottom or the door?

Comment: Describe the finish, insulation, and sun exposure of the garage. You may be feeling radiant heat from walls, ceiling, door, etc; a fan may do little to help with this (if it's a factor).

Comment: What color is the roof?

Comment: I live in Oregon and although not a hot location my garage easily reached over 100 degrees in the late spring summer and early fall. I put a solar roof fan on the western side of my garage it gets hot in the afternoon and I have full sun for 8 hours plus this time of year keeping the garage below 75f the temp switch turns off below that temp. I have had similar results in my last 3 homes adding exhaust fans is one of my first priorities to the house and garage.